# Split data by difference between rows values

Tags: r

I'm looking to split dataset per 10 days properly. The step between days is not alway 1 : could be 2 in the case of -149 -> -147

Is there any way smarter than test every time difference between days and register begin and end indexes for split ?

```
df = structure(list(day = c(-155, -153, -152, -151, -150, -149, -147, 
-146, -145, -144, -143, -142, -141, -140, -139, -138, -137, -135, 
-134, -131), margin = c(0.02, 0.03, 0.065, 0.06, 0.07, 0.05, 
0.035, 0.06, 0.0266666666666667, 0.03, 0.04, 0.06, 0.0366666666666667, 
0.035, 0.09, 0.12, 0.045, 0.04, 0.02, 0.06)), row.names = c(NA, 
-20L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: @TTS : There's some jump in the days sometimes
Suppose I have 155,145,143,142 -> i will take only 155,145

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An option is to get the `diff` of adjacent elements of 'day' column, then do the cumulative sum (`cumsum`), to create a the `diff` column, use that column to create a grouping with `%/%` for splitting at each 10 value as this returns an index that increments on every 10, then use that column in `group_split` to split the data into `list` of data.frames

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
 mutate(diff = cumsum(c(0, diff(day))), 
      diff = pmax(0, (diff - 1)) %/% 10) %>%
 group_split(diff, .keep = FALSE)
```

Comment: Thanks, In the first tibble  contains only -155, why ?

Comment: @ranell I think i made a typo in it.  Can you check the update

Comment: This looks perfect, didn't know the group_split(), thanks a lot !